# Replacing tables with divs

Tags: html, dreamweaver

I'm trying to convert an old design, that has tables, with divs. I read somewhere that you could use Dreamweaver but when I go to

MODIFY >> CONVERT >>Tables to AP Divs

that option is disabled. Adobe lacks documentation on this.
Any help?

Comment: damn you adobe. i just found this in the smallest letters imaginable:
Note: You can’t convert AP elements to tables or tables to AP Divs in a template document or in a document to which a template has been applied. Instead, create your layout in a non-template document and convert it before saving it as a template.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's something wrong with the html, take a look at your code, look for nesting errors, if there's a table being used for data arrangement like "text, images and other tables".

Nesting errors looks like:

```
</table></tr></td>
```

Comment: nah even when i create a brand new html document in DW and add a table through DW, it disabled. I've tried selecting it, changing views...still nothing

Comment: I can verify this, nothing I do will make it active